Various errors on a chart object after running a few times
I get an error message, typically one of the following three:

6: overflow
-2147467259: Method 'HasTitle' of object '_Chart' failed
-2147467259: Automation error, Unspecified error

Occurs on .hasTitle = true or any attempt to modify the chart.
The code as written (different variable names) works when I restart the PC. After running it a few times I get the error.  This seems indicative of a memory leak.
Sub testCode()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim chrt As Chart
  Dim i As Integer
  
  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  On Error Resume Next
  If (sht.Shapes.Count > 0) Then
    For i = sht.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
      sht.Shapes.Item(i).Delete
    Next i
  End If
  On Error GoTo errorHandle
 
 ' create a base progress chart.  Later I will add multiple series programmatically
 
 sht.Cells(27, 1).Select   ' select range below any existing data so chart will be empty
 Set shp = sht.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine, 750, 1, 800, 505)
' Set chrt = shp.Chart
' With chrt
'     .HasTitle = True
'     .ChartTitle.Caption = "Analysis"
'     .HasLegend = True
' End With
 
 shp.Chart.HasTitle = True
 shp.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = "Analysis"
 shp.Chart.HasLegend = True

 GoTo theEnd

errorHandle:
Debug.Print Int(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description

theEnd:
End Sub


Can't reproduce your error, even running that code many times (20k runs in a loop).

So . . . based on your results, the code segment is good.  After putting Excel down for a couple hours then opening the app, both the test code and the actual code are working fine.  No Changes.  Still sounds like a memory leak in vba.   I have not had an immediate issue with creating the series. That may be contributing to it.

You might consider adding a Doevents after the creating of the shape and maybe a wait timer (application.wait).
Try it with a clean excel (so empty office clipboard, no other workbooks open). If you are using 32 bits Excel it's more likely to have memory issues (See here for more info).
Also you might consider releasing used objects at the end of the code (eg sht= nothing etc)
Does it also crashes when you debug the code?
